# Java Questions! About List and Objects

Tags: java, list, object, methods

I have one List (linked list) that contains few objects. 
More specifically, the list is called EmployeeList that stores my Employee objects.
Each Employee has a variable salary (double).

I want to create a method in class EmployeeList that could raise the salary of EVERY Employee object in the list once it is called.

Anyone knows how to reach that?

Great thanks!

```
class Employee {

private double salary;
/**
 * sets the value of salary to "newSalary"
 */
public void setSalary(double newSalary) {
    salary = newSalary;
}

    /**
 * returns the current value of salary
 */
public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
```

Comment: Post your existing code for Employee class. Basically you will need to loop over your List.

Comment: This looks like something from a homework question. We don't do homework. We solve problems. Come back if you have an actual problem you can't actually GOOGLE to solve.

Comment: yes it is part of my homework. I'm really sorry.

Comment: I apologize, sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
double increase = 10000;

for (Employee employee : theList) {
    double salaryNow = employee.getSalary();
    employee.setSalary(salaryNow + increase);
}
```

Caution - you should **never** use a `double` to store an amount of money, as you will be subject to floating point rounding errors.  Please use a `BigDecimal` instead.  I've only done it in this snippet here to match what you have in your `Employee` class.